# How to remove Server Temp Key from SSL Certificate Chain

Tags: security, ssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

When I test my connection to my server:

> echo q | openssl s_client -connect abc.def.com:8443

I get back (extract):

> No client certificate CA names sent
>   Peer signing digest: SHA512.
>   Server Temp Key: ECDH, P-256, 256 bits

and

> New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384.
>   Server public key is 2048 bit

Can anyone tell me how to remove the Temp Key - I know almost nothing about security but guess having a temp key and / or one that is 256 bits (or that doesn't match the public key) is less than desirable.

I have tried to solve this, having found this:

https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/142274/what-does-server-temp-key-mean-in-an-openssl-output

&

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31441070/how-to-remove-just-one-certificate-from-a-certificate-chain-in-a-java-keystore

but with no success.

To explain my lack of success with the second link ....

pemfile.pem contents (redacted!):

```
Bag Attributes
friendlyName: gateway-identity
localKeyID: 54 69 6D 65 20 31 35 36 38 30 32 37 34 38 35 37 30 37

Key Attributes: <No Attributes>
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIE...
...
...
v4mZMVyvG63TmtJx6OtP0Zs=
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
Bag Attributes
    friendlyName: gateway-identity
    localKeyID: 54 69 6D 65 20 31 35 36 38 30 32 37 34 38 35 37 30 37
subject=/C=US/ST=Test/L=Test/O=Hadoop/OU=Test/CN=abc.def.com
issuer=/C=US/ST=Test/L=Test/O=Hadoop/OU=Test/CN=abc.def.com
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
MIID...
...
...
6WLAiy7LML8p0Da1WKom6L2HqyFKg6qltqEO5x16LrV4
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

Deleting the certificate and it's preceding bag attributes causes an error when I execute:

> openssl pkcs12 -export -in pemfile.pem -name gateway-identity -out
>   new.p12

I get:

> unable to load certificates

This makes sense to me.

Am I looking at this from the wrong angle? Is there some other way to disable / remove the temp key?

Answer (score 1):

> I know almost nothing about security ...

Yes, it looks like that based on this question.
While it is not that much of a problem if you know almost nothing, it is actually a problem if you jump to unfounded conclusions anyway. This can do more harm than good.

> ... but guess having a temp key and / or one that is 256 bits (or that doesn't match the public key) is less than desirable.

Wrong guess. This key is relevant for the ECDHE key exchange and 256 bits are perfectly fine when used with elliptic curves.

> How to remove Server Temp Key from SSL Certificate Chain

The key is not part of the certificate chain in the first place so it cannot be removed from there.

In short: nothing you show in your question indicates a security problem.